# Why is the use of 'from' behind the table name allowed? What does it do?

Tags: sql, database, db2, relational-database

SQL for DB2 is pretty strict, that's why I was surprised this query succeeded:

```
select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 from
```

Is it exactly the same as?

```
select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

If the double `from` is allowed, why isn't a double `where/select/order by/having` allowed? Is there any difference in the output when running this query on a 'real' table?

Comment: ANSI SQL has `FROM` as a reserved word, and I'm surprised DB2 allows that keyword as table alias (without having it delimited.)

Comment: @jarlh A yes maybe it's just a table alias after all. I can however not use 'where' as a table alias, but I am allowed for 'from'. Weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Db2 (for Linux, Unix, Windows) provides a list of reserved schemas and words](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001095.html). As stated in the docs, the list is not enforced by Db2, but the recommendation is to not use them for portability reasons.

A **from** succeeds but not a **where** because an optional **WHERE clause** follows in the place you tried to use the reserved words. In that case you have an incomplete **WHERE clause** and it violates grammar rules. Thus, the recommendation is to respect the list of reserved words and not use them. You may (freedom of expression... ;-) ), but you should be considerate...